# error while using sed in tcsh alias

Tags: linux, alias, tcsh, csh

I am unable to "source/run" my `tcsh` alias, which is as below:

```
alias inp1 "grep -i "final_model" /scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/$USER/\!:1/Simulation/Input/assemble.preprocessing | sed 's#.*<##; s/>$//'"
```

- where `\!:1` = Manual input
- Desired Output = `/scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/$USER/test/Simulation/Input/X1_X_XXXX_XXXXXX15X_H10EK011.inp`
- I will use additional alias (predefined) on Desired Output =

  ```
  alias inp2 "gdyn `grep -i "final_model" /scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/$USER/\!:1/Simulation/Input/assemble.preprocessing | sed 's#.*<##; s/>$//'`"
  ```

---

- first issue = solving non-compatible variable error (while sourcing alias file)
- second issue = can i have both outputs in single alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `csh`, the variable substitution **always** occurs within double quotes, and cannot be prevented by a backslash:

```
% echo "$"
Illegal variable name.
% echo "\$"
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
% echo "\\$"
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
% echo \$
$
```

This is different from the bourne shell and is documented in the [manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/csh.1#Variable_substitution)[1]:

> After the input line is aliased and parsed, and before each command is
>        executed, variable substitution is performed, keyed by `$` characters.
>        This expansion can be prevented by preceding the `$` with a `\` except
>        **within double quotes (`"`), where it always occurs**, and within single
>        quotes (`'`), where it never occurs.  Strings quoted by backticks (`` ` ` ``)
>        are interpreted later (see Command substitution below), so `$` substitution does not occur there until later, if at all.  A `$` is passed
>        unchanged if followed by a blank, tab, or end-of-line.

The easiest way out for your alias may be to start/stop the double quoting before/after the `\$`:

```
alias inp1 "grep -i 'final_model' /scr/cb2TempProd/tmp/$USER/\!:1/Simulation/Input/assemble.preprocessing | sed 's#.*<##; s/>"\$"//'"
```

For your second alias, I think you should simply reuse `inp1` instead of trying to paste it in:

```
alias inp2 'gdyn `inp1 \!:1`'
```

[1] that's the manpage of `csh`, but the quotings & substitutions are absolutely similar in `tcsh`.

Comment: I did. works well.
is it possible to have both outputs in one alias ?

Comment: you mean both `inp1` and `inp2`? maybe `alias inp3 'set v = \`inp1 \!:1\`; echo "$v"; gdyn "$v"'`

Comment: klassik....works well too... :)
Thank you very much for quick & correct support.